# Keras - Freezing A Model And Then Adding Trainable Layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am taking a CNN model that is pretrained, and then trying to implement a CNN-LSTM with parallel CNNs all with the same weights from the pretraining.

```python
# load in CNN
weightsfile = 'final_weights.h5'
modelfile = '2dcnn_model.json'

# load model from json
json_file = open(modelfile, 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
fixed_cnn_model = keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
fixed_cnn_model.load_weights(weightsfile)

# remove the last 2 dense FC layers and freeze it
fixed_cnn_model.pop()
fixed_cnn_model.pop()
fixed_cnn_model.trainable = False

print(fixed_cnn_model.summary())
This will produce the summary:
```

_

```python
________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 32, 32, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        1184      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 2, 128)         73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1, 1, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               66048     
=================================================================
Total params: 224,256
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 224,256
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now, I will add to it and compile and show that the non-trainable all become trainable.

```python
# create sequential model to get this all before the LSTM

# initialize loss function, SGD optimizer and metrics
loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4, 
                                beta_1=0.9, 
                                beta_2=0.999,
                                epsilon=1e-08,
                                decay=0.0)
metrics = ['accuracy']

currmodel = Sequential()
currmodel.add(TimeDistributed(fixed_cnn_model, input_shape=(num_timewins, imsize, imsize, n_colors)))
currmodel.add(LSTM(units=size_mem, 
            activation='relu', 
            return_sequences=False))
currmodel.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu')
currmodel.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')

currmodel = Model(inputs=currmodel.input, outputs = currmodel.output)
config = currmodel.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics) 
print(currmodel.summary())

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_3_input (In (None, 5, 32, 32, 4)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_3 (TimeDist (None, 5, 512)            224256    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                112600    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              52224     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 2050      
=================================================================
Total params: 391,130
Trainable params: 391,130
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

How am I supposed to freeze the layers in this case? I am almost 100% positive that I had working code in this format in an earlier keras version. It seems like this is the right direction, since you define a model and declare certain layers trainable, or not.

Then you add layers, which are by default trainable. However, this seems to convert all the layers to trainable.

Answer (score 3):

try adding

```
    for layer in currmodel.layers[:5]:
        layer.trainable = False
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 1):

First print the layer numbers in you network

```
for i,layer in enumerate(currmodel.layers):
    print(i,layer.name)
```

Now check which layers are trainable and which are not

```
for i,layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(i,layer.name,layer.trainable)
```

Now you can set the parameter 'trainable' for the layers which you want. Let us say you want to train only last 2 layers out of total 6 (the numbering starts from 0) then you can write something like this

```
for layer in model.layers[:5]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[5:]:
    layer.trainable=True
```

To cross check try to print again and you will get the desired settings.

Comment: You need to `compile` the model again to make it work